# segmentation fault when reading from file to buffer

Tags: c, sockets, buffer, fread

I need to read a file and then send it through a socket, but fread crash for some reason.
Any idea?

```
//Get file length
fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
int fileLen=ftell(fd);
fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);

//Allocate memory
buf=(char *)malloc(fileLen+1)* sizeof(char));
if (!buf)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Memory error!");
}
rewind(fd);

fread((void *)buf, strlen(buf)+1, 1, fd);
```

Comment: You get the 'Notwork' badge: str*() in network code.  Hint: what do you think strlen() actually does?

Comment: `strlen(buf)` or `sizeof(buf)`?

Comment: Also can you not get error for it `buf=(char *)malloc(fileLen+1)* sizeof(char));`? because missing `)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few basic confusions in that code.

- [`ftell()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ftell) returns `long`, not `int`. Also it should be `const`, since the file's size is assumed not to change while we read it.
- There's no need to call `rewind()` *and* use `fseek()` to offset 0.
- [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).
- You are not dealing with strings, so don't add one for some "terminator".
- Don't scale allocations by `sizeof (char)`, that's always 1.
- Check that the allocation succeeds before relying on the result.
- Don't cast the buffer pointer to `void *` in `fread()`, that's completely pointless.
- Use the file length in the `fread()`, calling `strlen()` on an undefined pointer is undefined behavior.
- Verify that the `fread()` succeeds.

Comment: Thanks! I was just wondering what the deeper sense of all this was... `fread (&buf, ... )` would have been perfectly sufficient, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
fread((void *)buf, strlen(buf)+1, 1, fd);
```

should be

```
fread((void *)buf, 1, fileLen, fd);
```

You did not initialized the contents of `buf`, so `strlen(buf)` will not return the correct length of `buf`.

By the way, `buf=(char *)malloc(fileLen+1)* sizeof(char));` should be `buf=(char *)malloc(fileLen);`, there is no need to allocate that extra byte, and `sizeof(char)` always returns 1.

Comment: Heh - missed that '*'.  As soon as I see strlen in network code, I'm blind to anything else.

Comment: Actually strlen return the right dimension of the buffer, i've checked using a printf. I also tried your solution but it did not work

Comment: printf("\nbufSize = %d", strlen(buf)); it's printing the number of byte of the opened file. I tried to use sizeof and it goes segmentation fault in the printf

Comment: @NLK511 can post more source?

Comment: Also, how big is the file?

Comment: @NLK511 You already knew the length of `buf`, it is `fileLen+1`, you used it in `malloc()` to allocate that `buf`, so why do you try to figure it out wrongly by `strlen(buf)`?